# Login via Ajax to the same page you were in with Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I've understood that the login is managed by `Auth > LoginController`

And I need to change this line to change the navigation :

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

However I've tried to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it is not accepted in this class.

[image]

What could I do to manage what I'm trying to do and why can't I use $_SERVER there?

Comment: How are you planning to handle the web page response in your ajax request?  Changing the redirection route alone won't help you here. You might need to overwrite more login controller methods to convert all response to json. I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are laravel methods that make your life easier for what you're trying to do. Inisde AuthController, there is this function called `authenticated`. You can do this inside it:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
{
  if (Auth::check()) {
     return redirect()->intended('your/url');
     //with named route
     return redirect()->intended(route('your.route.name'));
  }else{
     return $next($request);
  }
}
```

The `intended()` method will fetch the URL the user was trying to access, if it doesn't exist, it will redirect to the route or URL given as parameter.

### For Laravel >= 5.3

Go to `Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated` and on the `handle` function, modify it in order to look like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
  if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
      return redirect()->intended('your/url');
  }

return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I do not see this funciton (Im on Laravel 5.3)

Comment: @Baldráni Sometimes, changes on those files don't apply instantly, run the `php artisan config:cache` command or `php artisan cache:clear` after making those changes.